# Null checks in nested objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can these checks be made short, crisp and clean?

```
if (newConfig && 
    newConfig.options &&
    newConfig.options.interaction &&
    newConfig.options.interaction.applyFilteringOnGrid &&
    newConfig.options.interaction.applyFilteringOnGrid.searchFilters) {
            const gridFilters = Object.keys(newConfig.options.interaction.applyFilteringOnGrid.searchFilters);
            for (let i = 0; i < gridFilters.length; i++) {
                    logger.log('Grid Filters used',
                        {gridfilter: `${gridFilters[i]} filter`});
            }
    }
```

Comment: if(newConfig.options.interaction.applyFilteringOnGrid.searchFilters)

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal the duplicate of the comment by guru?

Comment: i suggest to use an array with keys and reduce the object by taking a default object. at the end you need to check just before you try to get the keys. `const
        getP = (o, k) => (o || {})[k],
  path = ['options', 'interaction', 'applyFilteringOnGrid', 'searchFilters],
        gridFilters = Object.keys(path.reduce(getP, newConfig) || {});`